# Does storing (caching) an object with large number of fields can effect on the performance in the Angular Application?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, browser-cache

Suppose, I have an object named `cachedData` and I am storing different page data as an objects assigned with its page name.

I traverse to new page, an api is hitted and load the page data and store that page into an `cachedData` object.

And when I traverse through any of the previous routes, instead of hitting the api of that page, I would get the page data from the `cachedData` object. By doing so, I am maintaining a cache of different pages data without reloading the page in angular application.

> Angular verison: 13

```
// Initally on load the application
cachedData:any = {};

// When I traverse through different pages, I update the cachedData object.
// when traverse through page 1;
cachedData = {
  page_1: {... 'n' amount of data present here ...}
}

// when traverse through page 2;
cachedData = {
  page_1: {... 'n' amount of data present here ...},
  page_2: {... 'n' amount of data present here ...}
}

// similarly when traverse through page '1000';
cachedData = {
  page_1: {... 'n' amount of data present here ...},
  page_2: {... 'n' amount of data present here ...},
  ...
  ...
  ...
  page_1000: {... 'n' amount of data present here ...}
}
```

As the time cross without reloading the page, my `cachedData` is very **large** and **heavy**.
Does it effect on the performance of the Angular application?

I am implementing the local cache concept in the application, I doesnot know that, does this approach will affect my angular application's performance.